# How to get Id in ext.net, Code line return null (extjs)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I try to use below line to get ID, it works fine in Ext.Net V1.x but create problem with V2.X with IE10.

```
var f=Ext.get('<%=BtnID.ClientID%>');
```

as the same get function does't work with any extjs control.

Same thing happen with:

```
var jj = Ext.get(<%=grd.ClientID %>.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: some code snippet will help - if work on all, but IE10, then maybe is a bug on the library extjs

Comment: this happens in upgradation process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ... in V2.x, we can access controls without Ext.get. like;

```
var f=<%=BtnID.ClientID%>;
```

Comment: var jj = Ext.get(<%=grd.ClientID %>.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0]); is still not working